# Application under Wine cannot access any serial ports?

Tags: wine, serial-port, radio

I'm trying to run [this program](https://www.kenwood.com/i/products/info/amateur/mcp_2a.html) under Wine (that's programming software for a Kenwood TM-V71 radio). The software installs and runs without a problem, but when it comes time to select a serial port everything is greyed out:

[image]

Wine autodetects all the serial ports just fine:

```
$ ls -l $WINEPREFIX/dosdevices/com*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 18 Aug  6 00:38 /home/lars/.wine/tmv71//dosdevices/com1 -> /dev/usbserial/1/6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 10 Aug  6 00:38 /home/lars/.wine/tmv71//dosdevices/com2 -> /dev/ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 12 Aug  6 00:38 /home/lars/.wine/tmv71//dosdevices/com34 -> /dev/ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 12 Aug  6 00:38 /home/lars/.wine/tmv71//dosdevices/com35 -> /dev/ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 12 Aug  6 00:38 /home/lars/.wine/tmv71//dosdevices/com36 -> /dev/ttyUSB2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 12 Aug  6 00:38 /home/lars/.wine/tmv71//dosdevices/com37 -> /dev/ttyUSB3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 10 Aug  6 00:38 /home/lars/.wine/tmv71//dosdevices/com6 -> /dev/ttyS4
```

The corresponding devices nodes are:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root dialout 188, 0 Aug  6 00:05 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root dialout 188, 1 Aug  6 00:31 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root dialout 188, 2 Aug  6 00:05 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root dialout 188, 3 Aug  6 00:05 /dev/ttyUSB3
```

I am a member of the `dialout` group, and I can access all the serial ports under Linux without a problem.

I have created an expolicit mapping via `regedit` (following [these instructions](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports)) from `com1` to `/dev/usbserial/1/6`, which right now is just a symlink to `/dev/ttyUSB1`:

```
 $ ls -l /dev/usbserial/1/6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug  6 00:05 /dev/usbserial/1/6 -> ../../ttyUSB1
```

What else needs to happen in order for this application to successfully access a serial port under wine?

I'm using Wine 8.12 on Fedora 38.

Comment: not a solution, but a silly little workaround here https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=1625 (search for "ser2net")